# Other approach for the fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

[inclusion of connected manifold of dimension $\geq 3$ minus point induces isomorphism of fundamental groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3451224/707075)

I was wondering if there is another approach to solve this problem without using the van Kampen theorem?

1) I was able to prove that $i_{*}$ induced by the inclusion is surjective. What about injectivity? I feel like it is trivial. But I am afraid I am missing something. (Homotopic in the punctured set implies homotopic in the set.)

2) Also, I might be able to prove it directly if $M \setminus \{p\}$ is a path-component of $M$. Is it true?

Remark, M is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \ge 3$. So it is not an arbitrary manifold (might make things easier).

Answer (score 2):

If you know the actual proof of Van Kampen's Theorem, it is not at all hard to use the technology of the proof to directly show that the map $i_*$ induced by inclusion is injective. What you have to prove is that if a closed loop $\gamma : [0,1] \to M$ has image contained in $M \setminus \{p\}$, and if $\gamma$ is path homotopic to a constant in the whole manifold $M$ then $\gamma$ is also path homotopic to a constant in $M \setminus \{p\}$ (where $p$ is distinct from the base point of $\gamma$).

In brief outline, to do this, choose a path homotopy $H : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to M$. Choose a small open ball $U$ around $p$, and let $V = M \setminus \{p\}$. One obtains an open cover $H^{-1}(U),H^{-1}(V)$ of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. Applying the Lebesgue Number Lemma to this open cover, one obtains a subdivision of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ into little squares each of which has $H$-image contained in $U$ or $V$. Now is the tricky part: On each of those little squares whose image is contained in $U$, you have to change the function $H$ to avoid the point $p$, and this is best done in coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the backwards statement for injectivity: "$\pi_1(M\setminus\{p \}) \to \pi_1(M)$ is injective" means that (homotopic in $M$) $\implies$ (homotopic in $M\setminus \{p\}$).

To prove injectivity you have to show that if a loop in $M\setminus \{p\}$ has a null-homotopy $H\colon I\times I \to M$ through $M$ then $H$ can be made to avoid $p$. If $M$ is a *smooth* manifold you could use Differential Topology to achieve this, by invoking [smooth approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550856/continuous-function-approximation-on-manifolds) and the [transversality theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_theorem), since the dimensions of $\{p\}$ and $I\times I$ sum to less than the ambient dimension ($0 + 2 < 3\leq dim (M)$) so in this case "transverse" means "disjoint".